# Using binary search in ArrayList to find a word with a given prefix

Tags: java, string, arraylist, compare, binary-search

I am working on implementing a binary search algorithm to find a word that contains the prefix argument. This is what I have at the moment but the output isn't correct.

```
    public static int myBinarySearch2(List<String> arrayList, String prefix) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = arrayList.size() - 1;
    int mid = 0;

    while (first <= last) {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        int c = prefix.compareTo(arrayList.get(mid));
        if (c > 0) {
            first = mid + 1;
        } else if (c == 0) {
            return mid;
        } else
            last = mid - 1;
    }
    return mid;
}
```

If anyone can look at my code and provide me so feedback, id appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Change `return mid:` to `return -1;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `boolean startsWith(String prefix)` instead of `int compareTo(String s)`.

The last one compares strings `char` by `char` fully, it isn't what you are expecting.

```
String s = arrayList.get(mid);
int c = s.startsWith(prefix) ? 0 : prefix.compareTo(s);
```

Comment: How do you get int from boolean?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use compareTo method to check for a word containment.

CompareTo Method:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm

You may want to use .contains method:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm

Answer (score 1):

First remember that arrayList needs to be sorted to use binary search, if not their return is undefined. I think that is your problem.